# Differences between types of black holes

Tags: black-holes, mass, astrophysics

What are the differences between stellar black holes, intermediate black holes, supermassive black holes and miniature black holes?

Answer (score 1):

They have different masses.  Since the black hole horizon is order of magnitude $M$ from the center of the black hole (the exact proportionality constant depends on spin, ranging from 1 to 2), and since the "surface gravitational force" at the horizon is proportional to $\frac{M}{r^{2}} = \frac{1}{M}$, this means that the smaller the black hole is, the more severe any general relativistic effects that are visible at the horizon are.  In particular, if the black hole collides with another object, the frequency of the gravitational waves emitted will be mostly determined by the masses of the objects involved, which will affect which gravitational wave detectors will be sensitive to the signal (LIGO has a different sensitivity range from bar detectors, which are both different from the proposed LISA project, for example).

Comment: Thank you Jerry 